# How do I indicate that a column in a data table has been added or changed?

Tags: tables, data-tables, indicator, column-headers

1. I have a data table where I let people toggle columns (Show/Hide)
2. A few columns also change based on the value of a dropdown the users select inside a modal that controls table settings
3. How do I indicate to the user on screen that the column they just added appeared at position 20 or the column they modified is right there look
   Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few suggestions

1. Have a collapsed/hidden view of the column (ex. slightly smaller and greyed out)
2. Have a toggle to hide & unhide columns/elements that the user can easily see and click on
3. Have a global alert message that notifies the users of any changes that might have occurred.
4. Have contextual links in the alert message that by clicking on them the user will highlight and focus on the area that has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

Do a little UI highlight animation on the column(s) updated. It could be a short pulsing effect for the highlight. Example... not *exactly*, but something like this: https://dribbble.com/shots/2201819-Pulsing-Pin-in-Framer

[image]